# Make a string out of a single tab character

Tags: c#, string

I want to create a string that consists of a single character such as '\t' and that's it, however the String class constructor won't accept it.

```
String myTab = new String( '\t' );
```

This gave me:

> Error  2   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'char' to 'char*'

Okay, I thought I wouldn't need pointers after switching from C++, but I'll give you one then:

```
char oneChar = '\t';     
String myTab = new String( &oneChar );
```

Gives:

> Error 1   Pointers and fixed size buffers may only be used in an unsafe context

So I tried this clumsy conversion instead without success:

```
String myTab = new String( ToString('\t') );
```

The error I get here is:

> Error  3   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'char[]'

This is the simplest issue ever and it irritates me a lot. Can anybody tell me how to solve it and why the string class isn't made to accept single characters?

Comment: Why don't you write `"\t"` ?

Comment: You are missing character count (`1` in your case) - [`new String('\t', 1)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsa4321w%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 7):

`char` and `string` are **different** data types. You can't use a `char` where a `string` is expected (or for that matter, where a `char*` or `char[]` are expected).

The constructor that takes `char*` can only be used in an `unsafe` context (see other answers), but unless you've got a real good reason for going `unsafe`, don't do it (however tempting it is with your C++ background).

`'\t'` defines a `char`

`"\t"` defines a one character `string`

As such wouldn't

```
string myString = "\t";
```

be fine?

If you want to convert a `char` into a `string`

```
string myString = myChar.ToString();
```

Comment: Explain why quotes are different from apostrophes, and you've got my upvote.

Comment: Yes, but the string constructor accepts both char* and char[] as an argument, so I don't get why it wouldn't accept char.

Comment: It's because neither `char*` nor `char[]` are `char`. The constructor you believe exists does not.

Comment: @spender constructor from `char` indeed [exists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsa4321w%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), it just expects count of characters to repeat.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov : Sure... that is evident from the docs. I'm sure the OP has read them.

Comment: Perfect, there we have it :)

Answer (score 2):

You don't normally "instantiate" a string object, and you certainly don't assign a string to a char.

The following will compile:

```
String test = "\t";
```

This is the normal way of doing what you ask.

Comment: From my java point of view that would only create a reference to a string, which illegaly would be assigned the value '\t'. But here it's different then. Hmm.

Comment: String *references* are not immutable, only string values. That line of code creates a variable of type string and assigns the (immutable) value `"\t"` to it.

Answer (score 1):

While spender's answer addresses your main issue, I thought I might answer your issue with the pointer.

The error `Pointers and fixed size buffers may only be used in an unsafe context` means that you need to tell the compiler you're using potentially unsafe code, by wrapping it in an `unsafe` block:

```
unsafe {
    char oneChar = '\t'; 

    String myTab = new String( &oneChar ); 
}
```

..would then be fine.

But, you also need to let the compiler know that you're going to be using unsafe code by enabling it in the project settings:

[image: Enable unsafe code]

Comment: Ooo, so that's how it's done. Guess I could have use for that someday, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you want in a number of ways. Just off the top of my head, that includes (but probably isn't limited to):

```
string s1 = '\t'.ToString() ;
string s2 = new string( new char[]{'\t'} ) ;
string s3 = new string( '\t' , 1 ) ;
string s4 = new StringBuilder().Append('\t').ToString() ;
```

Or, since you already know the character in question:

```
string s5 = "\t" ;
```

I suspect that all of the 1st 4 will likely be optimized away into the 5th form.